# Angular Variables inside SVG

Tags: angularjs, svg

```
Error: Invalid value for <text> attribute x="{{xForLabels.text}}"
angular.js:2390 Error: Invalid value for <text> attribute x="{{xForLabels.textNumber}}"
angular.js:2390 Error: Invalid value for <circle> attribute cx="{{xForLabels.circle}}"
angular.js:2390 Error: Invalid value for <text> attribute x="{{xForLabels.text}}"
angular.js:2390 Error: Invalid value for <text> attribute x="{{xForLabels.textNumber}}"
```

I use angular scope variables for attributes inside svg, everything works as i expect, but in console i get this errors. how to get rid of them? thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you should try `ng-attr-x="{{xForLabels.text}}"`

ref: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#-ngattr-for-binding-to-arbitrary-attributes

Comment: Saved my day. Thank you. The updated link for the ng-attr is https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#-ngattr-for-binding-to-arbitrary-attributes